# /kafka_2.11-2.1.1/kafka_2.11-2.1.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: C:\Program: No such file or directory

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to start kafka broker in windows. I have zookeeper running in my system. 
Command used

```
./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server1.properties
```

Error:

```
/d/software/kafka_2.11-2.1.1/kafka_2.11-2.1.1/bin/kafka-run-class.sh: line 306: C:\Program: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

It was because I was trying to start kafka in windows.
For windows the the kafka scripts are within "bin\windows" directory. When updated my command to include kakfa scripts from windows directory, the issue got resolved.

./bin/windows/kafka-server-start.sh config/server1.properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes it occured with me too. Ran with scripts in windows directory, solved the problem.

```
./bin/windows/kafka-server-start.sh config/server1.properties
```